# How do we get the Alexa Account Linking Card to display (working with Jovo)

Tags: node.js, auth0, alexa-skills-kit, jovo-framework

```
if (!this.$request.getAccessToken()) {
    return this.alexaSkill()
        .showAccountLinkingCard()
        .tell('Go the Alexa app and set account linking');
}
```

We're trying to authenticate users in an Alexa app through Auth0. We're developing the experience on Jovo, but the account linking card isn't displaying.

We're able to manually link the accounts by going into the app's settings, but we're hoping to display the authentication webview without adding those steps.

This is the tutorial we're following: https://www.jovo.tech/tutorials/alexa-account-linking-auth0